# Como hago dos columnas de mis tablas en pdfmake-wrapper con angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf

Estoy tratando de que mis dos tablas esten una al lado de la otra pero al tener un ciclo for de por medio me bloquea un poco para realizarlo, el pdf lo estoy diseñando con pdfmake-wrapper de angular.

La tabla donde estan los numeros de color azul quiero que este al lado de la tabla "Modulo Prueba". Tal cual como esta "Competencias a Evaluar" y "Calificacion"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo:

```
for (const modulosPreguntas of this.modulosPreguntas) {
      pdf.add(
        new Table([
          [new Txt (modulosPreguntas.nombre_Modulo).color('white').end],
        ]).widths(['*', '*', '*']).layout({
          fillColor: (rowIndex) => (rowIndex === 0 ? '#3f60a8' : '#ffffff'), // Color de fondo de la tabla
        }).end
      );
      for(const preguntas of modulosPreguntas.preguntasByEvaluacionModel){
        pdf.add([
          new Table([
            [preguntas.pregunta],
          ]).widths(['*', '*', '*']).end
        ]);
      }
      
    }
    
    for (const key in this.evaluaciones[0]) {
      if (key.startsWith('clfc_Pregunta')) {
        const numero = key.substring(13); // Extraer el número desde la posición 13 hasta el final del string
        const calificacion = this.evaluaciones[0][key as keyof ListaEvaluacionesInterface];
        
        // Buscar el objeto preguntasByEvaluacionModel que tenga el mismo número de pregunta que 'numero' en todos los elementos de this.modulosPreguntas
        let preguntaEncontrada = null;
        for (const moduloPregunta of this.modulosPreguntas) {
          preguntaEncontrada = moduloPregunta.preguntasByEvaluacionModel.find(p => p.numero_Pregunta === Number(numero));
          if (preguntaEncontrada) {
            // Si se encuentra la pregunta correspondiente, salir del bucle
            break;
          }
        }
        
        if (preguntaEncontrada) {
          // Si se encontró la pregunta, agregarla al PDF
          pdf.add(
            new Table([
              [calificacion], // Agregar el número de pregunta junto a la calificación y el texto de la pregunta
            ]).widths(['*', '*', '*']).layout({
              fillColor: (rowIndex) => (rowIndex === 0 ? '#3f60a8' : '#ffffff'),
            }).end
          );
        }
      }
    }
```